# Are formal groups associated to various groups different?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups, formal-power-series, formal-groups

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group and $X$ be an abelian variety over $Spec(R)$, where $R$ is a commutative noetherian ring. Let $\widehat{G}$ and $\widehat{X}$ be the completion along the identity section $\epsilon_G : Spec(R) \rightarrow G$ and $\epsilon_X : Spec(R) \rightarrow X$ respectively. Then one can see that $\widehat{G}$ and $\widehat{X}$ are formal groups. It is clear that a homomorphism of groups give a homomorphism of the associated formal groups. Since $G$ is affine and $X$ is an abelian vairety there cannot be any non-trivial morphism from $G$ to $X$. My question is the following :

*Question 1.* Does there exist groups $G$ and $X$ and a non-trivial morphism (an isomorphism) $\phi : \widehat{G} \rightarrow \widehat{X}$? In particular, I would like to know if one can detect whether the group is affine or projective using the associated formal groups.

*Question 2.* In the paper titled $p$-divisible groups, the author J. Tate raised the following question : Are there any $p$-divisible groups over $\mathbb{Z}$ other than the products of powers of $\mathbb{G}_m(p)$ and of $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$? I suppose this has been asked in light of the fact that there are no abelian schemes over $\mathbb{Z}$ and then only one-dimensional affine algebraic groups are $\mathbb{G}_a$ and $\mathbb{G}_m$. The $p$-divisble group assiated to $\mathbb{G}_a$ is Is that correct? What is currently known about this problem?

The two questions seem rather disconnected but I suppose they can be put down under the same ubmrella of $p$-divisible groups and hence the reason for putting them down as one question.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For the second question see Theorem 4 of Fontaine's article *Il n’y a pas de vari´et´e abelienne sur $\mathbb{Z}$*. For your first question, are you aware that over a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra every one-dimensional formal group is isomorphic (by the log map)?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you very much! I know the theorem you mention for my first question. But I guess I couldn't connect the dots. I would appreciate some comment on the current status of the problem asked by J. Tate in the paper mentioned in the second question. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you look at the cited theorem of fontaine where he classifies $p$-power group schemes over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (partial?) answer to your Question 1 only.

Since you have left your ring $R$ completely unspecified, I’ll give an example when $R$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$. Perhaps you knew this special case already?

The example takes $G$ as the multiplicative group $\mathbf G_{\text m}$ and $X$ as an ordinary elliptic curve over the field $R$. Then their formal groups, being both of height one, are $R$-isomorphic.